# Android which way is bettter for upgrading free app version to paid version

Tags: android

Hi all I am developing android application I have to launch add free and ads enable version of the application
but I want to implement if user installed ads enable version then he can upgrade it to the ads free version
there are two way to do this

1. we give a link of(add free version of app) in the ads enable version
2. I implemented a separate unlocker for our ads enable version

Kindly let me know which way is better and professional

Answer (score 1):

Why not have just one free version (with ads), and then let them disable the ads within the app via in-app purchase?

Answer (score 1):

The benefits of unlocking the app as opposed to creating a separate 'unlocked' app are much greater.

You only have a single source code.
You have more control over who installs your 'premium' content as no matter who installs the apk, only premium users get the premium benefits.
The Play Store handles the in app purchase (and reunlocking of an already purchased upgrade) with very little difficulty from either a developer or a users point of view.

Which is more professional? I'm not sure there is a definitive answer to that, it's been done both ways by many people.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, In-app purchase is the best way to go. You can have one application only, and provide a way (for example, in settings) to the user, so that he/she can buy to remove the ads.

For more, check the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323097/in-app-purchase-remove-ads).