# Can Android in-app purchase modify access permissions

Tags: android, permissions, in-app

I am curious if it is possible to change an App's access permissions using an in-app purchase?

The App I am developing has access to network / internet and advertising.
To improve user's privacy, there will be an in-app purchase option that will disable ads and remove network / internet support.

I know that I could do a separate app entirely, but I'd prefer to keep it within the same app.

I have searched and cannot find a solution to my particular use case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an in-app purchase it isn't gonna change any permissions. Permissions are set on the manifest and is not changeable.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change permissions is with an upgrade to a newer version, as @SuperThomasLab pointed out, the permissions are in the manifest and set in stone for that version.

Google has very strict requirements that the user needs to be informed of any permission changes on each upgrade, so there is absolutely no way to change the permissions that the user agreed to the last time they installed your app.

You can add functionality to disable the code that uses any network/internet, even if the permission is still there.

As for removing ads, see this post: [In-App Purchase remove ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323097/in-app-purchase-remove-ads/13323235#13323235)