# A simplified way to purchase the paid version of an application

Tags: android, admob

I'm preparing an application in two versions: free of charge with
advertising
 and a paid version without ads. I'm wondering how to resolve the
issue of purchasing the paid version: clicking on the menu and then
going to Google Play, or maybe there is a better and faster way?
Recently I've seen an interesting solution (screenshots below), which lets
 the user buy the ad-free version in one click. Do you happen to know
how to implement this method?
Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-App Purchase remove ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323097/in-app-purchase-remove-ads)

Answer (score 0):

> Quick Fix:

You can Launch two different version of your app free and paid one or else when the user transaction is verified, enroll his email address to closed track release (ad free). He'll get the update for the ad free version within minutes. or [SOFLOW reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323097/in-app-purchase-remove-ads)