# How to remove android ads (admob) from the source code

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am trying to adapt an opensource android app to my own project, and I need to remove the android ads. I've tried to remove them but I don't know how and I always get errors here and there. Is there any easy way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it....

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549401/correctly-disable-admob-ads
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323097/in-app-purchase-remove-ads
```

please check above links it will help you.

Remove below code from your application

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

<xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
   android:id="@+id/adView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   ads:adSize="BANNER"
   ads:adUnitId="a1513ffd4f3e17c" />
```

Comment: Those links show how to disable them within the app, to give the option to able or disable. I just want to recompile the app without them. I guess I'll have to remove something in the manifest but I don't know exactly how

Comment: @user2182013 : Now check the answer

Comment: @user2182013 : What happen?

Comment: It seems to work, thank you! And sorry for the late answer.