# How to OFF admob ad for specific URL in WebView

Tags: android, admob, android-webview

I am working on an Android Webview. I have integrated AdMob Banner & Interstitial ads in my APP.
My question is how to put OFF AdMob when the user hit specific URL in WebView. 
Like I want to OFF AdMob when the user opens Facebook.com via WebView.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you mean how to switch off.. "how to off X" is an informal way to say "how to murder X"

Comment: you don't know how to listen to webview url changes, or how to hide admob banner?

Comment: Thanks alot for quick response :)
I have a webview App and in webview i have "Login with Facebook" button that also open in webview. When someone click "Login with Facebook" then it redirect to facebook.com and ask for Email & Password. I want when user redirect to facebook.com then admob OFF and did not show ad banners. 

Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/EqUjiTL.png

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549401/correctly-disable-admob-ads